# Heat Equation on a disc

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, bessel-functions

Question: The temperature distribution $u(r, θ, t)$ in a circular disc of unit radius $(0 ≤ r < 1, 0 ≤ θ < 2π)$ evolves according to the heat equation with unit thermal diffusivity $$u_t = ∇^2u$$ where $∇^2$ is the Laplacian in Polar Coordinates. The outer edge of the disc is insulated so that the normal gradient of the temperature at the boundary satisfies $u_r(1, θ, t) = 0$. The initial temperature distribution is $u(r, θ, 0) = f(r)$. By seeking axisymmetric ($θ$-independent) solutions, show that the temperature at time $t$ is given by

$$u(r, t) = A_0 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty A_k J_0 (\alpha_k r)exp(-\alpha_k^2 t)$$

Find the coefficients ${α_k}$ and obtain integral expressions involving $f(r)$ for the coefficients ${A_k}$.

Can anybody help me with this question? I've used the seperated solution $u(r,t) = R(r)T(t)$, and found $T(t)=Aexp(-\lambda t)$. Using the fact that $R(0)=finite$ the conditon $u_r(1, θ, t) = 0$, I got $R'(1) = B\sqrt\lambda J_0'(\sqrt\lambda)=0$, where $J_0$ is the Bessel function of the first kind, index $0$. I dont really know how to find the eigenvalues and figure out what $\alpha_k$ is. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're determined by this condition "$R'(1) = B\sqrt\lambda J_0'(\sqrt\lambda)=0$"; that is "the eigenvalues are such that the square root is a zero of the derivative of $J_0$" (in particular finding the eigenvalues and finding $\alpha_k$ amounts to the same thing; though finding $A_k$ is done, as usual, by using your initial condition and orthogonality, and so will be defined in terms of integrals of $f$ against $J_0(\alpha_k r)$).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. As far as I know, there are infinitely many maximum and minimum of the Bessel Equation, so would you just assume $B\sqrt\lambda$ does not $= 0$ and then just say $J_0'(\sqrt\lambda) = 0$ implies $\sqrt\lambda = j_(0k)$, where $j_(0k)$ are the zeros of the Bessel Function?

Comment: You should investigate the case $\lambda = 0$ separately (this is where $A_0$ comes from). Then, for the $\lambda \neq 0$ cases, you can assume $B\neq 0$ either (otherwise it's just a trivial solution). Now you're close to the right idea, but we want the zeros of the **derivative** of $J_0$, not $J_0$ itself. (but otherwise, it should suffice to say "$\sqrt{\lambda}$ are the zeros of the derivative of $J_0$" because you're probably not expected to know/calculate these actual values)

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you mean by investigate the case when $\lambda=0$ separately. Do you mean plug $\lambda = 0$ into the $T=exp(-\lambda t)$ equation? And then would the $\alpha_k$ simply be $j_0_k^2$? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: When you separate variables, you get a diff eqn for $R$, involving $\lambda$. If you assume $\lambda$ isn't zero, you get Bessel functions as solutions to this DE. If you assume it is zero, you get constants as solutions. Compare to the case of solving this PDE on a line segment or rectangle: you separate variables and get an equation like $X'' + \lambda X = 0$. If you assume $\lambda > 0$, this leads to sines and cosines. If $\lambda = 0$ however, the corresponding solution is $X$ constant. (and you include all possible solns to the eigval problem when writing the series solution to the PDE).

Comment: In the example you gave, $X'' + \lambda X = 0$, if $\lambda = 0$ then wouldn't $X = Ax + B$, by just integrating $X'' = 0$ twice.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was getting ahead of myself. The general solution is linear $Ax + B$, but after applying insulating boundary conditions ($X'(0) = X'(1) = 0$) you find $A = 0$.

Comment: Got it. Final question (I promise!) is that would all of this then just lead to $\alpha_k = \sqrt\lambda$ where $\lambda$ just the zeros of the derivative of the Bessel Function, order 0 i.e $\lambda = j_{0k}^2$? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: If $j_{0k}$ is meant to be "the $k$th zero of the derivative of $J_0$" then yes, this is exactly what you want. (but I would be explicit about your notation here, because without clarification, I would assume "$j_{0k}$" is a zero of the Bessel, not the derivative of a Bessel)

Comment: When you take inner products to compute $A_k$, can you just ignore the $A_0$? Or would you take it over to the other side to get $f(r) - A_0$ and then take inner products with both of them separately to get $\frac{<f,R_k>_w - <A_0,R_k>_w }{<R_K,R_K>_w}$

Comment: Sorry I meant to type $A_k = \frac{<f,R_k>_w - <A_0,R_k>_w }{<R_K,R_K>_w}$

Comment: $A_0$ is basically the "average temperature" (equivalently, it is the steady-state solution, i.e. the temperature distribution as $t \to \infty$). Compute it among the rest of the inner product calculations for $A_k$, it should be of the form (up to some constants) $\int f(r) \,dr$. This is basically attained by taking an inner product with the eigenfunction $X_0 = \textrm{constant}$ which is orthogonal to $X_k(r) = J_0(\alpha_k r)$.

Comment: So you'd just be computing what I typed above for $A_k$? You honestly have no idea how much you've helped me!

Comment: Which would give $A_k = \frac{\int_{0}^{1} rf(r)J_0(\alpha_k r) dr - A_0\int_{0}^{1}J_0(\alpha_kr)}{\int_{0}^{1}rJ_0^2(\alpha_kr)dr}$, where $\int_{0}^{1}rJ_0^2(\alpha_kr)dr = \frac{J_0(\alpha_k^2)}{2}$

Comment: Yeah, and what is $\int_0^1 r J_0(\alpha_k r)$? (sorry, I think I have omitted some "r"s from some integrals)

Comment: is it not just $J_1(\alpha_k)$?

Comment: Should be zero. You're thinking of $\int r J_0^2(\alpha_k r)\,dr$.

Comment: hang on isnt $\int_{0}^{1}rJ_0^2(\alpha_kr)dr = \frac{J_0(\alpha_k^2)}{2}$ and $\int_{0}^{1}rJ_0(\alpha_k r)dr = J_1(\alpha_k)$?

Comment: sorry, I'm not explaining this well. First, $\int_0^1 r J_0^2(\alpha_k r)\,dr = \frac12 J_1^2(\alpha_k)$ only holds if the $\alpha_k$ are the zeros of $J_0$, and further, note that the square is in a different location. The other identity is correct, apologies here. **However**, using the facts that $J_0' = -J_1$ and the definition of $\alpha_k$, what can you say about $J_1(\alpha_k)$?

Comment: im presuming its 0, but im not sure why

Comment: Remember that $\alpha_k$ is defined by your boundary conditions: $J_0'(\alpha_k) = 0$.

Comment: Yup got it. Thank you for all your help!